# How does this equation relate to a Gaussian distribution and what does the comma mean?

Tags: probability, gaussian

Before the following equation, the text says "The note transcription method takes as an input the
pitch track and outputs discrete notes on a continuous pitch
scale, based on Viterbi-decoding of a second, independent
hidden Markov model (HMM). [...] The likelihood of a non-silent state emitting a pitch track frame with pitch q is modelled as a Gaussian distribution centered at the note’s pitch p with a standard deviation of semitones, i.e.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cc7cO.png)

where np is a state modelling the MIDI pitch p, z is
a normalising constant and the parameter 0 < τ < 1
controls how much the pitch estimate is trusted; we set
τ = 0:1. The probability of unvoiced states is set to
P(unvoiced|q) = (1 - v)=n, i.e. they sum to their combined
likelihood of (1 - v) and v = 0.5 is the prior likelihood
of a frame being voiced. The standard deviation
varies depending on the state: attack states have a larger
standard deviation (σ = 5 semitones) than stable parts (σ= 0.9).

I cannot see how this relates to these equation for Gaussian functions listed on Wikipedia:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fybew.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SeUxc.png)

Am I misunderstanding or can someone explain the relationship?

Moreover, does the comma in the equation mean, "or"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My *guess* is that they use just $\phi_{p,\sigma}(x)$ to mean:

$$\phi_{p,\sigma}(x)=\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{(x-p)^2}{2\sigma^2}}$$

or something similar. The comma is there just to separate $p$ and $\sigma$, nothing else.

However, I feel you have not provided enough context, as there is further multiplication with $v$ (?!), division with $z$ (?!) and something denoted as $(\cdot)^{\tau}$ (?!). I am just wary that there *might* be more to this, hidden in this missing context.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! I see what you're saying - I added some more context.

Comment: @eartoolbox I will still hold onto my guess. $(\cdot)^\tau$ is exponentiation and then they have to normalise the PDF (via $z$) and they are scaling it down by a factor $v$ - but this reinforces my guess that $\phi_{p,\sigma}$ is the (Gaussian) PDF to start with, as I stated above. You understand the actual text better than me - does this explanation make sense?

Comment: Yes it does, thank you!